# Why am I getting 'Method Not Allowed Error' in vercel

Tags: backend, mern, vercel

I developed this website- https://snotes00.vercel.app

but I am facing an issue while sending request to vercel backend- POST https://snotes00.vercel.app/server/login net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)
I was sending the request from- https://snotes00.vercel.app/login

While running in local server, it works alright., it causes this issue only in vercel.

I am running the front end on https://snotes00.vercel.app and backend on https://snotes00.vercel.app/server

Github repo- https://github.com/sayanbose-0000/snotes

Please help me fix it

[NOTE: I don't think there is an error in my code, cause it works fine in local server... Is there a problem in how I set up the env variables?]

Answer (score 0):

If you used the **Free plan** of Vercel this caused the issue. Because it provides only **Edge runtime** but **JWT cannot run on Edge runtime**. You need to use an alternative for authorization (e.g.: [jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose)) which is supported by Edge runtime.

In this discussion of official Vercel GitHub repo you can find an example implementation of jose: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43115#issuecomment-1321785193

Comment: Yes, I used the free version of vercel. Can you suggest a vercel free alternative if I want to keep using JWT

Comment: It's worth a try [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/pricing/#core-pricing-table) or [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting).

Comment: That is not true. You can run Serverless Functions on Vercel without any issues...

Comment: You have a `client` and a `server`. But I don't think you are deploying the `server` to the same URL as the client.
I believe you may need to include a line like `{"src" : "/server/(.*)","dest":"https://example-backend.vercel.app/$1"}` 
in https://github.com/sayanbose-0000/snotes/blob/main/client/vercel.json